Operator-Sdk : How to determine if disk is valid using golang
We are developing app controller which requires disk to be assigned to Pod. We get the disk details from user in yaml format and create PV/PVC and assign the disks to the Pod.
We do not have a mechanism to determine if the disk is passed is a valid disk unless the pod creation fails. Is there a way we can determine if the disk passed are valid disks? For example, we pass following:
apiVersion: app.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: SystemApp
metadata:
  name: systemapp-1
  namespace: app1
spec:
 appDetails:
   - name: app1
     port: 3030
   - name: app2
     port: 3031
 DiskDetails:
  diskName:
    - /dev/sdf1
    - /dev/sdg1
  workerNodes:
    - worker1
    - worker2

How do I know if /dev/sdf1 and /dev/sdg1 are valid devices before Pod failure? Can we validate these disks in Webhook if they really exist on mentioned worker nodes?

Sure. You'll need to run some sort of DaemonSet with a pod on each node that provides your controller with an API to verify the existence of local disk devices. The pods will need to run in privileged mode to have access to host devices.

@larsks, I really appreciate your feedback. I thought of this but I was trying to avoid privilege access to node as it brings security concern.

I don't think you're going to find any other way to determine whether or not a host device exists.

(Do you need to request a physical disk by device name?  Don't you need privileged access anyways to access a raw disk device?  Can you just create a PersistentVolumeClaim, and let the cluster manage storage and placement for you?)
